# Writing daemon, /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions hangs

Tags: init-script, init.d

I am writing my own service daemon for Fedora 23 and I stucked, when my script hangs while including source function library.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# service-live-text-relation <summary>
#
# chkconfig:   2345 80 20
# description: Starts and stops a single service-live-text-relation instance on this system
#

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: service-live-text-relation
# Required-Start: $network $named
# Required-Stop: $network $named
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: This service manages the service-live-text-relation daemon
# Description: service-live-text-relation
### END INIT INFO

#
# init.d / servicectl compatibility (openSUSE)
#
if [ -f /etc/rc.status ]; then
    . /etc/rc.status
    rc_reset
fi

echo "test1"

#
# Source function library.
#
if [ -f /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions ]; then
    . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
fi

#. /etc/init.d/functions

echo "test2";

#... further code goes here ...
```

I run following commands:

```
/bin/systemctl daemon-reload
chkconfig --add service-live-text-relation
chkconfig service-live-text-relation on
/bin/systemctl enable service-live-text-relation.service
```

When I run:

```
service service-live-text-relation start
```

I give the following output:

```
test1
Starting service-live-text-relation (via systemctl):
```

And the script hangs...

I have followed by example watching another scripts, but I cannot recognize what might be incorrect in my script.

Comment: add `set -x` somewhere near the top of the script (or, at least, before sourcing `/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions` which is where it seems to be hanging) to trace it.  that might tell you where it hangs.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are being bitten by systemd compatibility. In systemd-enabled systems, files in /etc/init.d are handled by systemd. The "service" command is just a shell script that tries to be "cute" (helpful) about starting a service for you. Have you tried just manually running '/etc/init.d/service-live-text-relation'?

I have no idea how the systemd compatibility works, so I can't help you there. If you have the proper "start", "stop", "restart" (etc) targets, like other init.d service control scripts, then I believe you can make them work.

But ... you *really* should be creating a systemd unit file instead. Perhaps try adding a unit file in /etc/systemd/user called 'service-live-text-relation.service'. Check out 'man systemd.service' (and all it's friends). It's becoming a systemd world, so you might as well update your start file. IMHO.